# Element is duplicated in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code move elements inside other elements to create a tree hierarchy.

```
<ul>
    <li id="task_111" class="task"><a>task1</a></li>
    <li id="task_222" data-in-task-group-id="333" class="task"><a>task3</a></li>
    <li id="task_333" class="task task_group">
      <a>task2</a>
      <ul data-task-group-id="333" class="task_group_list"></ul>
    </li>
    <li id="task_444" data-in-task-group-id="333" class="task task_group">
        <a>task4</a>
        <ul data-task-group-id="444" class="task_group_list"></ul>
    </li>
    <li id="task_555" data-in-task-group-id="333" class="task"><a>task5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Loop that moves the elements:

```
$('li').each(function() {
  task_group_id = $(this).attr('data-in-task-group-id');
  if (task_group_id) {
    $("li#task_" + task_group_id + " .task_group_list").append($(this));
  }  
})
```

All looks pretty simple but one element (task5) is copied wrong:

[image: tree]

As you see task5 is placed inside two parent elements: the correct parent is task2, task4 should be empty.

Why is task5 is copied wrong inside task4?

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fsLU6/4/) to play around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that `task4` - including its `<ul>` element with a class of `task_group_list` - is moved into `task3`. Then, when it's the turn of `task5` to be moved, there are multiple elements that match this selector:

```
li#task_333 .task_group_list
```

As stated in the [doc for append](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

> The `.append()` method inserts the specified content as the last child of **each element in the jQuery collection**

Since you have multiple elements you get `task5` appended to each of them, cloning the element as necessary.

You'll want to change your selector so that it only matches the `<ul>` that's an immediate child, rather than a descendent, of that `<li>` element:

```
li#task_333 > .task_group_list
```

The code for the loop would become:

```
$('li').each(function() {
    task_group_id = $(this).attr('data-in-task-group-id');
    if (task_group_id) {
        $("li#task_" + task_group_id + " > .task_group_list").append($(this));
    }  
})
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fsLU6/6/)

Comment: And you are right! Thank you so much for explaining this not so trivial (at least for me) issue.